# JavaScript that checks if every radio button is checked?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Hello I am new to JavaScript, so I need a little help.

I have this simple html form with radio buttons. There are 20 questions and every question must be answered, so I need some form of validation that will check if every question is answered before a visitor clicks submit button? (that checks if the radio buttons are selected)

Thank you in advance.

```
 <form action="rezultatiFU.php" method="post">


<ol>


<li>
    <h3>Koji ste pol?</h3>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer1' id='answer1' value='A' />
    <label for='answer1A'>Muško</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer1' id='answer1' value='B' />
    <label for='answer1B'>Žensko</label>
    </div>
    </li>

    <li>
    <h3>Koliko imate godina?</h3>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer2' id='answer2' value='A' />
    <label for='answer2A'>18-25</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer2' id='answer2' value='B' />
    <label for='answer2B'>25-35</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer2' id='answer2' value='C' />
    <label for='answer2C'>35-45</label>

    </div>
    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer2' id='answer2' value='D' />
    <label for='answer2D'><45</label>
    </li>



    <li>
    <h3>Koliko ste visoki? (cm)</h3>

    <div>
    <input type='text' name='answer3' id='answer3' />
    </div>
    </li>



     <li>
    <h3>Koliko imate kilograma?</h3>
    <div>
    <input type='text' name='answer4' id='answer4' />
    </div>
    </li>


    <li>
    <h3>Da li Vaš posao zahteva kretanje ili neku fizičku aktivnost?</h3>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer5' id='answer5' value='A' />
    <label for='answer5A'>Da</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer5' id='answer5' value='B' />
    <label for='answer5B'>Ne</label>
    </div>
    </li>


    <li>
    <h3>Da li ste dijabetičar?</h3>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer6' id='answer6' value='A' />
    <label for='answer6A'>Da</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer6' id='answer6' value='B' />
    <label for='answer6B'>Ne</label>
    </div>
    </li>


<li>
    <h3>Koliko tečnosti unosite tokom dana?</h3>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer7' id='answer7' value='A' />
    <label for='answer7A'>Ispod 2 litre</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer7' id='answer7' value='B' />
    <label for='answer7B'>2 litre</label>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer7' id='answer7' value='C' />
    <label for='answer7C'>Preko 2 litre</label>
    </div>
    </li>

    <li>
    <h3>Da li doručkujete?</h3>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer8' id='answer8' value='A' />
    <label for='answer8A'>Da</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer8' id='answer8' value='B' />
    <label for='answer8B'>Ne</label>
    </div>
     <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer8' id='answer8' value='C' />
    <label for='answer8C'>Ponekad, kada stignem</label>
    </div>
    </li>



    <li>
    <h3>Koliko često se bavite fizičkom aktivnošću?</h3>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer9' id='answer9' value='A' />
    <label for='answer9A'>Skoro nikada</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer9' id='answer9' value='B' />
    <label for='answer9B'>Jednom nedeljno</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer9' id='answer9' value='C' />
    <label for='answer9C'>Više puta nedeljno</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer9' id='answer9' value='D' />
    <label for='answer9D'>Svaki dan</label>
    </div>

    </li>



    <li>
    <h3>Koliko obroka imate tokom dana?</h3>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer10' id='answer10' value='A' />
    <label for='answer10A'>1-2</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer10' id='answer10' value='B' />
    <label for='answer10B'>3</label>
    </div>


    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer10' id='answer10' value='C' />
    <label for='answer10C'>5 i više</label>
    </div>
    </li>


    <li>
    <h3>Da li konzumirate hranu sa velikim udelom masti?</h3>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer11' id='answer11' value='A' />
    <label for='answer11A'>Da</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer11' id='answer11' value='B' />
    <label for='answer11B'>Izbegavam masnu hranu</label>
    </div>
     <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer11' id='answer11' value='C' />
    <label for='answer11C'>Ponekad</label>
    </div>
    </li>

    <li>
    <h3>Da li konzumirate hranu sa velikim količinama šećera? (slatkiši, sokovi sa šećerom i sl.)</h3>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer12' id='answer12' value='A' />
    <label for='answer12A'>Da, uživam u takvoj hrani</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer12' id='answer12' value='B' />
    <label for='answer12B'>Ne, izbegavam kad god mogu</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer12' id='answer12' value='C' />
    <label for='answer12C'>Ponekad</label>
    </div>
    </li>


        <li>
    <h3>Koliko često jedete voće i povrće?</h3>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer13' id='answer13' value='A' />
    <label for='answer13A'>Svaki dan</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer13' id='answer13' value='B' />
    <label for='answer13B'>Retko</label>
    </div>
    </li>


        <li>
    <h3>Koliko kalorija unesete tokom dana? (odprilike)?</h3>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer14' id='answer14' value='A' />
    <label for='answer14A'>Nedovoljno</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer14' id='answer14' value='B' />
    <label for='answer14B'>Dovoljno</label>
    </div>
     <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer14' id='answer14' value='C' />
    <label for='answer14C'>Previše</label>
    </div>
    </li>

        <li>
    <h3>Koliko često konzumirate alkohol?</h3>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer15' id='answer15' value='A' />
    <label for='answer15A'>Jednom nedeljno</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer15' id='answer15' value='B' />
    <label for='answer15B'>Više puta nedeljno</label>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer15' id='answer15' value='C' />
    <label for='answer15C'>Jednom mesečno</label>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer15' id='answer15' value='D' />
    <label for='answer15D'>Nikada ili jako retko</label>
    </div>
    </li>



    <li>
    <h3>Koliko često konzumirate hranu iz FastFood restorana?</h3>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer16' id='answer16' value='A' />
    <label for='answer16A'>Svaki dan</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer16' id='answer16' value='B' />
    <label for='answer16B'>Svaki drugi dan</label>
    </div>
     <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer16' id='answer16' value='C' />
    <label for='answer16C'>Jednom nedeljno</label>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer16' id='answer16' value='D' />
    <label for='answer16D'>Ne jedem u Fast Food restoranima</label>
    </div>
    </li>



    <li>
    <h3>Koliko često jedete pečenu hranu?</h3>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer17' id='answer17' value='A' />
    <label for='answer17A'>Svaki dan</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer17' id='answer17' value='B' />
    <label for='answer17B'>Svaki drugi dan</label>
    </div>
     <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer17' id='answer17' value='C' />
    <label for='answer17C'>Jednom nedeljno</label>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer17' id='answer17' value='D' />
    <label for='answer17D'>Ne jedem pečenu hranu</label>
    </div>
    </li>




    <li>
    <h3>Kada ogladnite a nije vreme za obrok, šta pojedete?</h3>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer18' id='answer18' value='A' />
    <label for='answer18A'>Čips</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer18' id='answer18' value='B' />
    <label for='answer18B'>Kokice</label>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer18' id='answer18' value='C' />
    <label for='answer18C'>Semenke, kikiriki, lešnik, badem</label>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer18' id='answer18' value='D' />
    <label for='answer18D'>Slatkiše</label>
    </div>  
    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer18' id='answer18' value='E' />
    <label for='answer18E'>Voće</label>
    </div>  
    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer18' id='answer18' value='F' />
    <label for='answer18F'>Popijem tečnost i čekam da pregladnim</label>
    </div>  
    </li>

    <li>
    <h3>Da li jedete i kada niste gladni?</h3>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer19' id='answer19' value='A' />
    <label for='answer19A'>Da</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer19' id='answer19' value='B' />
    <label for='answer19B'>Ne</label>
    </div>
    </li>



    <li>
    <h3>Okarakterišite sebe?</h3>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer20' id='answer20' value='A' />
    <label for='answer20A'>Optimista</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type='radio' name='answer20' id='answer20' value='B' />
    <label for='answer20B'>Pesimista</label>
    </div>
    </li>


    <br/>
    <input type="image" src="http://www.programtreninga.com/slike/dugmetest.png" alt="Submit Form" width="110" />

    <p><strong>* Napomena: morate odgovoriti na sva pitanja kako biste dobili tačan rezultat!</strong></p>
</ol>


</form>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Just FYI: Two HTML-elements should never have the same ID. The id-attribute should always be unique to a single element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way would be something like this:

```
if( document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]:checked").length < 20) {
    alert("You didn't answer all the questions");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can validate also using `jquery`.

```
var names = {};
$('input:radio').each(function() {
      names[$(this).attr('name')] = true;
});
var count = 0;
$.each(names, function() {
      count++;
});
if($('input:radio:checked').length == count) {
      // all questions answered
}
```